# Understanding bash find

Tags: bash

I was trying to learn bash basics. I was trying out how `*/.*` displays all invisible files in all subdirectories in folder `notes-bash`:

```
~/anir/repos/notes-bash$ find */.*
images/.
images/./bashrepl.png
images/..
images/../.git
images/../.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
:
del/.
del/..
del/../.git
del/../.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
del/../.git/HEAD
:
```

I am not getting why it is listing files as `images/..`. Doesnt that mean same folder as `notes-bash`? I guess it is simply trying to find `/.` in all possible directories. Thus it recurs through all subdirectories (here `images` and `del`) to force form paths with `/.` as substring.

**Q1.** Am I correct with this?

So I next created subdirectory `del/del1` and ran following command to check all paths formed passing through `del1`:

```
$ find */.* | grep del1
del/./del1
del/../del/del1
images/../del/del1
```

**Q2.** So, now I am guessing why it did not recur through `del1`, that is why it did not list paths such as `del/del1/../../.git`?

Comment: `bash` doesn't have a `find` command; it's an external program.

Answer (score 1):

> I was trying out how */.* displays all invisible files in all subdirectories in folder `notes-bash`

This will list all files starting with a `.` in the current directory and all subdirectories:

```
~/anir/repos/notes-bash$ find -name '.*'
```

> I am not getting why it is listing files as `images/..`

It's because the first `*` in your `find` matches a directory named `images` inside `notes-bash`.

> I next created subdirectory `del\del1`

No, you didn't. You created a subdirectory named `del` and possibly subdirectory of that named `del1`. `del/del1` would be the appropriate reference to it.

Your guess regarding why `del1` isn't showing up everywhere is a bit off. Just do

```
echo */.*
```

and see what it displays. Those are the files and directories that your `find` command will work with.

Comment: I tried `echo */.*` and it printed `images/. images/.. de/l. del/..` but did not contain `del/de1/.` and `del/de1/..`. Now the question is why so? Is it that `find` tries to form path only with the help of subdirectories of current directory and not sub-subdirectories? In the other words, why first `*` in `*/.*` does not get resolved to `del/del1`? I just came acrorss the rule that "`*` is not expanded to include `/`" Is it the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: What that echo prints is the files and directories that `find` will search through. You can go through them manually to verify it. `*/.*` does not match `del/del1`. What makes you think that it would? You have a . In your glob and `del/del1` does not.